# Change EXIF meta-data of multiple images in single click

Tags: software-recommendation, graphics, metadata, exif

I ran into big problem yesterday night.

I took out my old digital camera, and started using it without setting current date and time.

All photos clicked now have date as Jan 01, 2009

I want to change the date and time (and other EXIF image meta-data) of multiple images.

Please recommend some software which can process on multiple images in single click/go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) is the one to go for.

It has a time shift feature that allows you to shift the dates.

> > **Date/Time Shift Feature**
>
> Have you ever forgotten to set the date/time on your digital camera
>   before taking a bunch of pictures? ExifTool has a time shift feature
>   that makes it easy to apply a batch fix to the timestamps of the
>   images (ie. change the "Date Picture Taken" reported by Windows
>   Explorer). Say for example that your camera clock was reset to
>   2000:01:01 00:00:00 when you put in a new battery at
>   2005:11:03 10:48:00. Then all of the pictures you took subsequently
>   have timestamps that are wrong by 5 years, 10 months, 2 days, 10 hours
>   and 48 minutes. To fix this, put all of the images in the same
>   directory ("DIR") and run exiftool:
>
> *exiftool "-DateTimeOriginal+=5:10:2 10:48:0" DIR*
>
> The example above changes only the DateTimeOriginal tag, but any
>   writable date or time tag can be shifted, and multiple tags may be
>   written with a single command line. Commonly, in JPEG images, the
>   DateTimeOriginal, CreateDate and ModifyDate values must all be
>   changed. For convenience, a shortcut tag called AllDates has been
>   defined to represent these three tags. So, for example, if you forgot
>   to set your camera clock back 1 hour at the end of daylight savings
>   time in the fall, you can fix the images with:
>
> *exiftool -AllDates-=1 DIR*
>
> See [Image::ExifTool::Shift.pl](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/Shift.html) ([download in PDF format](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/Shift.pdf)) for
>   details about the syntax of the time shift string.

**Some things to note:**

Test on a small batch of copies first until you get the date syntax you want.

I suggest you copy or move your images to a new folder first.
And run the command on that directory.

If you run exiftool on a directory it will look in sub directories and modify any image files it finds.

Exiftool WILL automatically append '_original' on the end of your original files and create a new copy for you with the modifications.

You can override this by using the '-overwrite_original' option.

```
exiftool  -overwrite_original -AllDates+="0:2:1 10:48:0" /Users/UserName/Desktop/testFolder
```

This example shifts forward   0 years, 2 months, 1 day,  10 hours, 48 minutes, 0 seconds.

Using a single set of time shifts i.e instead of "0:2:1 10:48:0" you use "10:48:0". 
Exiftool will see this as hh:mm:ss.
And you can omit 0 where you do not want to put a shift.

```
exiftool  -overwrite_original AllDates+="9::" /Users/UserName/Desktop/testFolder
```

This example shifts forward 9 hours.

```
   exiftool  -overwrite_original -AllDates-="9::" /Users/UserName/Desktop/testFolder
```

This example shifts back 9 hours.

Notice AllDates-="  and AllDates+="  , one has a plus one has a minus.

Also Remember you are **shifting** time not stamping a time stamp.

So if my original date was :
*2011:07:21 01:41:29*

and I used `exiftool  -overwrite_original -AllDates-="24::" /Users/UserName/Desktop/testFolder`

Then I would get : *2011:07:20 01:41:29*

Do download the PDF with the syntax

And make sure you look at the difference with the options -overwrite_original_in_place  and -overwrite_original

[Documentation](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html)

Answer (score 1):

iPhoto and Aperture can do this too.

On iPhoto, select the images. Go Photos -> Adjust Date and Time and make the calculation you need to correct the date. tick the box to adjust the Original files and click ok

Answer (score 1):

OS X Photos app has this functionality built in, under Image -› Adjust Date and Time.

It opens a dialog showing current time stamp and prompting for corrected one.
If multiple images were selected, date and time of the first photo is shown; the adjustment is used to calculate time shift to apply to all selected photos.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried any of the other answers, but [GraphicConverter](http://www.lemkesoft.com/) is a great program for batch processing images (as well as good standalone image editing software) and can edit metadata as well. GraphicConverter is available through the developer's [web site](http://www.lemkesoft.com/) or the Mac App Store.

Comment: It actually uses the exiftool engine :-)

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. Makes sense though, I guess! :D

Answer (score 0):

my best pick for you would be Xnview with its "change timestamp" option under "tools" menu.

Its robust and let you change all five (3x Exif and 2 file) date/time attributes belonging to a single photo.

This tool works in batch mode with adjusting days, hours, minutes, seconds and picking the correct date/time of specific photo.

You can see which date/time attribute will be applied and you can choose which of those five date/time attributes will be affected

Answer (score -1):

I used [EXIF Pilot](http://www.colorpilot.com/products.html) with [Batch Edit Plugin](http://www.colorpilot.com/exiffarm_edit-batch.html) when I had this issue. Unfortunately, it's Windows-only.

[ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) was recommended to me and I see they have an OSX package but I haven't used it.